# Develop a "Mark as read | Mark as unread" Button in Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm trying to develop a new feature for a Chrome extension targeting Gmail. The idea is to make the current "Mark as read" button [1] a bit smarter, i.e. when an unread conversation is checked, propose the current "Mark as read" button and whenever a read conversation is checked, propose a new "Mark as unread" button.

An excerpt of the JS script is available below (resting on jQuery).

The issue I have is that the behaviour of the button, either in state "mark as unread" or "mark as read" is persistent. More precisely, once Gmail is loaded and an unread (read) conversation is clicked in the inbox, then a button "Mark as read" ("Mark as unread") button is displayed in the navigation and the selected conversation is marked as "read" ("unread") whenever the latter button is clicked, as it should. When another conversation is selected in the inbox, the content and attribute are still changed accordingly, **but** the behaviour of the button keeps being the same as the previously clicked event, e.g. :

1. First conversation selected after Gmail load is a read conversation
   -> Mark as unread button is displayed and once the latter button clicked, the selected conversation becomes unread;
2. Second conversation selected is an unread conversation -> Mark as read button is
   displayed (with correct "act" attribute) but once the button is
   clicked, nothing happens... the "cached" behaviour of the button is still
   "Mark as unread"!!
3. Vice-versa is true.

Any ideas/help appreciated !

*Disclaimer: Note that I'm perfectly aware of the right-click function, keyboard shortcut or "more" menu-entry in order to mark read | unread conversations in Gmail. The reason I wish to implement such a functionality is due to some requests coming from the users of my Chrome extension.*

[1] :  Button created by the Gmail lab "Mark as read"...

```js
/* load at document_end (manifest.json) 
 * and wait for main Gmail frame to be loaded */

$("#canvas_frame").ready(function() {

// [...]

function UnRead(elem) {

   // Select Gmail button "Mark as read"
   var readBtn = $('.Cq .m9.ar7');

     /* Change the behavior and content of the button 
      * depending on the state of the conversation selected. 
      * In Gmail, act = 2 : mark as unread | act = 1 : mark as read */

     if ( typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem.match('yO') ) {
       readBtn.empty().attr('act', '2').wrapInner('Mark as unread');
     } else {
       readBtn.empty().attr('act', '1').wrapInner('Mark as read');
     }
}

/* Detect whether the user clicks on a conversation and call
 * UnRead fn with the class argument of the conversation. 
 * In Gmail, CSS class "zE" denotes an unread email while 
 * class "yO" denotes a read email. */

$('.Cp tr').on('click', function() { UnRead($(this).attr('class')) });

// [...]
});
```

Comment: I see how you change the button's label and `act` property, but how is the button's behaviour affected (i.e. where is the relevant code) ? Is `readBtn` an element injected by your extension or is it created by GMail itself (I couldn't find any such element in my GMail) ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, readBtn selects the Gmail button created by the Gmail lab "Mark as read button".